# How to Inject HTML on ASP.NET MVC master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, google-analytics

I have a simple, but probably common problem on how to inject HTML inside an ASP.NET MVC master page. I have a google analytics tracking code that sits on my master page. The code looks like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
// need to inject ecommerce code here
(function () {
    // google analytics code here
})();
```

I'm using ecommerce tracking and I want to inject the "cart" information in side this HTML on the receipt page (and ONLY on this page). So I do something like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
<% if(ViewData["googleanalytics"]!=null) {%>
<%= ViewData["googleanalytics"] %>
<% } %>
(function () {
    // google analytics code here
})();
```

Then in the controller, I have code that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Receipt()
{
    var receipt = // get receipt model

    // get google analytics javascript. This function pulls
    // the data from the receipt model
    ViewData["googleanalytics"] = GetAnalyticsInfo(receipt); 

    return View(receipt);
}
```

This whole thing seems like a little bit of a kludge and I was wondering if anybody had better ideas to handle this situation?

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Which part bothers you the most? As I understand your question is that Google Analytics code is constant for the whole site, but eCommerce code is per page or something?

Comment: You could write a filter to set the GA code in ViewData and put it on the Receipt action. (I think this is one of the rare scenarios where it's appropriate to use ViewData.) There really isn't anything wrong with leaving it inside the action though.

Comment: Yes, the ecommerce is only for the receipt page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you split the javascript into two parts:

At the top of your master page, put:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

At the bottom of your master page, put:

```
(function () {
    // google analytics code here
})();
```

And then, somewhere in your receipt page's view (where it will be output in between the two pieces of javascript from the master page), put

```
<% if(ViewData["googleanalytics"]!=null) {%>
<%= ViewData["googleanalytics"] %>
<% } %>
```

Worth a try?

Answer (score 4):

I think I misread your original question. If this has to happen on only one page, then adding a filter would be a 'cleaner' option.

**Filter:**

```
public sealed class GAFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       filterContext.Controller.ViewData["googleanalytics"] = GetAnalyticsInfo();
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }

   private MvcHtmlString GetAnalyticsInfo()
   {
   }
}
```

**Action:**

```
[GA]
public ActionResult ()
{
    return View();
}
```

It would be nice if you could bind a strongly-typed viewmodel to a MasterView but the current MVC framework does not allow that. ViewData is your friend for pushing info from a Controller into a Master.

Comment: Since GetAnalyticsInfo() requires access to the model, how would I get this information?

Comment: When you say Model, are you referring to the ViewModel or the DataModel? I would just keep this info in the web.config's App settings or get from a Config DB.

Comment: Either one. Let's say the ViewModel for argument's sake. The point is that the GetAnalyticsInfo() must return the user-specific receipt information. And this is generated in the controller.

Comment: Per my understanding, there is no ViewModel for a MasterView since a View can have only one ViewModel.

You have access to the Controller via the ActionExecutingContext.

Update: see code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you want the GA code to be applied across the board on all pages? In that case, you can abstract the account ID into a helper class like so:

`public class Configuration
{`

public string GoogleAnalyticsId
        {
            get
            {
               return "INSERT_ID_HERE";
            }
        }

}

You can then reference this in a partial view. Push the entire JS into an .ascx file (under Views\Shared)

`var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%=Configuration.GoogleAnalyticsId%>']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
// need to inject ecommerce code here
(function () {
    // google analytics code here
})();`

Now, add a Html.Partial to your master

`<%=Html.Partial("GoogleAnalyticsControl")%>`

Comment: The issue is you're still not pulling the google analytics code for the particular receipt.

Answer (score 0):

`public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
MyController myController = (MyController)filterContext.Controller;
myController.GetAnalyticsInfo();
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}`